# Need Entry Table with tkinter in the same window ? How to get entry with the tktable?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am developing an application in which a list of values to be entered from the user and each time of loading of the app the rows changes hence I cannot go with the text or entry option for each time. Does anyone have any good suggestions?

Comment: There is nothing to prevent using the Text or Entry widgets. Why do you think that’s a limitation?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read
[what this site is about](https://stackoverflow.com/about) and 
"[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)" 
before asking a question.

Comment: Thanks for the reply bryan!!!!

Comment: I need values to be stored and the text area should be refreshed. do you have any suggestions?